# Spring SFTP Integration Occasional error IOException: Pipe closed

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, sftp

Hi i am integrating the SFTP (Version 5.1.6)into my spring boot application. Below is the configuration i am using . But sometime i am getting below exception and failing the transfer, not sure what is the issue how i can make sure there is no exception occurs.

> Failed to write to 'TestFile.xml.writing' while uploading the file;
> nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: failed to write file; nested
> exception is 4: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
    LOGGER.debug(" Creating SFTP Session Factory -Start");
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    factory.setHost(sftpHost);
    factory.setPort(sftpPort);
    factory.setUser(sftpUser);
    factory.setPassword(sftpPasword);
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    LOGGER.debug(" Creating SFTP Session Factory -End");
    return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
}

 @Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
    LOGGER.debug(" Creating SFTP MessageHandler - Start ");

    handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(sftpRemoteDirectory));
    handler.setFileNameGenerator(new FileNameGenerator() {
        @Override
        public String generateFileName(Message<?> message) {
            if (message.getPayload() instanceof File) {

                return ((File) message.getPayload()).getName();
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected Input is File.");
            }
        }
    });
    LOGGER.debug(" Creating SFTP MessageHandler - End ");
    return handler;
}

@MessagingGateway
public interface UploadGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "toSftpChannel")
    void sendToSftp(File file);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pipe closed

Simply means there was a network glitch or the server closed the connection for some reason; you will need to look at the server logs for more information.

You can add a retry advice to the outbound adapter to retry failures.

Comment: Can you please give some more insight on how i can do retry on failures ?

Comment: See [Adding Behavior to Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain). Specifically, configure a [Retry Advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#retry-advice) `@Bean` and add its bean name to the `@ServiceAcivator`'s `adviceChain`.